# Java sockets on Android, black screen when I try to connect to certain IPs

Tags: java, android

I wrote a server-client system in Java (the client is on both Windows and Android). Everything works fine except one thing: When I try to connect the socket to an IP where no server is running, my program throws an error via an AlertDialog on Android, and via a `System.out.println("ERROR: bla bla bla...");` and all works fine. But there are some IPs that freeze my devices. Black screen appears and after 20/30 seconds the app stops responding.

Here is my code:

```
public class Client {

   // stuffs

    public void connect() {
        try {
            socketContainer = new CreateSocket(ip, port).execute().get();
            if (socketContainer != null) {
                connected = true;
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        }
    }

   // Other stuffs

    private class SocketContainer {
        private Socket socket;
        private ObjectOutputStream out;
        private ObjectInputStream in;

        public SocketContainer(Socket socket, ObjectInputStream in, ObjectOutputStream out) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.out = out;
            this.in = in;
        }

        public Socket getSocket() {
            return socket;
        }

        public ObjectOutputStream getOut() {
            return out;
        }

        public ObjectInputStream getIn() {
            return in;
        }
    }

    private class CreateSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SocketContainer> {

        private String address;
        private int port;

        private CreateSocket(String address, int port) {
            this.address = address;
            this.port = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected SocketContainer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(address), port), 7000);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                return new SocketContainer(socket, in, out);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SocketContainer sContainer) {
            super.onPostExecute(sContainer);
            synchronized (lock) {
                socketContainer = sContainer;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is CreateSocket ? An asynctask. Dont use .get() on it!!!

Comment: Why? SocketContainer object is created with the .get() method of CreateSocket

Comment: No its created with the `new` operator. Get rid of that .get().

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by myself!

I place the solution for those who have the same problem:
From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

AsyncTask has `public final Result get ()` method and `public final Result get (long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`. I replaced `socketContainer = new CreateSocket(ip, port).execute().get();` with `socketContainer = new CreateSocket(ip, port).execute().get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. In this way, if the client fails to connect to the server in 5 seconds, will be thrown an Error (in my case an AlertDialog).

Comment: Always nice to find a solution oneself. But... Very bad 'solution'. Get rid of that .get() and handle the result of doInBackground in onPostExecute. That's how you should use an asynctask. Write 'normal' code.